# Everything I try to assign after penny moves 1 down. So nickels gets assigned to dimes, dimes to quarters etc

Tags: c

For some reason I cant figure it out. I tried something as a filler in order to make it assign a dummy. But now there is a blank line after asking for pennies and its being assigned to nickels and quarter value isn't being assigned to anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 char first, middle, last, yes;
 int quarter, dime, nickel, penny, quarvalue, dimevalue, nickelvalue, pennyvalue, sum, nothing;
 float totalpennies;

 printf ("Hello, please enter your initials ");
 scanf ("%c", &first);
 scanf ("%c", &middle);
 scanf ("%c", &last);

 printf ("Welcome %c", first);
 printf (".%c", middle);
 printf (".%c.", last);

 printf ("\nEnter number of pennies:");
 scanf ("%d\n", &penny);

 printf ("Enter number of nickels:");
 scanf ("%d\n", &nickel);

 printf ("Enter number of dimes:");
 scanf ("%d\n", &dime);

 printf ("Enter number of quarters");
 scanf ("%d\n", &quarter);

 printf ("\nnumber of pennies is %d", penny);
 printf ("\nnumber of nickels is %d", nickel);
 printf ("\nnumber of dimes is %d", dime);
 printf ("\nnumber of quarters is %d\n", quarter);

 
 sum = (25 * quarter) + (10 * dime) + (5 * nickel) + penny;
 totalpennies = sum/100;
 
 printf ("\nyour coins are worth:%d",sum);


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `\n` from your scanfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't written C in many years but my first guess is that your `\n` is being interpreted as an [ENTER] and so you're ending up with one extra return at every point.

Comment: If I removed the `\n` before asking for pennies, it just puts my initials and question for pennies on the same line, but after I give the value for pennies it goes to a blank line and assigns that to nickels and continues with the same skipping issue. 

EDIT
Nevermind! after removing all `\n`'s it seemed to have done the trick

Comment: Notice that in this tutorial they don't add any display or control characters to the input string for scanf
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm
Try `scanf ("%d", &penny);` I'm pretty sure that will solve your problem.

Comment: Worked! Thank you sir.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
totalpennies = sum/100;
```

by

```
totalpennies = sum/100.0;
```

as you have `100` in the first case, you are using an `int` variable (`sum`), divided by an integer literal, so integer division is used, and you will get the integer quotient of it.

In the second case, you are dividing an integer `sum` by a double floating point literal (`100.0`) which means the compiler will use floating point division, giving you the correct answer in `totalpennies`.  Despite the fact you don't use that value, and the other responses.  This is only the two cents I can contribute to your case. (my pun here)